# some of my hdri thumbnails won't load, why?

Tags: hdri

[image]

All hdri's are from hdri haven and all files work when loaded but some thumbnails don't show in the menu. Are they too big of a file or something?

Comment: Yep. They are too big for your computer to handle. Also, if you have too many hdri thumbnails, there is a possibility that your blender might crash, but it depends on you PC specifications and how much it can handle.

Comment: ah cool thanks, ill download a 1k version for those so i can see the the thumbnail. yeah found that out haha

Comment: In fact making the catalogue of maps is somehow better cause You could have all maps in SUPER-HIGH resolution and simply choose the right one for your scene from catalogue. The other reason for doing so is that Blender makes thumbnails everytime You open-up that folder (at least in my experience).